# tel: link is not working, whenever i'm clicking on number it show's 'Unfortunately the app has stopped' and terminates the app

Tags: android, asp.net

I have created asp.net website, for which i have developed an Android app using webview, in asp.net i have given mobile number links using tel: , and in android i  have provided all the permissions which are needed for calling, then also whenever m clicking on telephone number it shows 'Unfortunatly app has stopped', I'm not getting why its not working, please help me solve this.

this is maninActivity.java

```
package com.example.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    view.reload();
                    return true;
                }

                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        mWebView.setInitialScale(1);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);

        mWebView.loadUrl("http://advisor.royaldevelopers.co");
        // Stop local links and redirects from opening in browser instead of WebView
         mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
    }

    // Prevent the back-button from closing the app
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

this is android.mainifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
    <user-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></user-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Royal Advisor App"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="Royal Developers" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity

            android:name="com.example.app.MainActivity"
            android:label="Royal Developers" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: post error log please

Comment: I'm not getting any error while building an apk, but while accessing app , and on clicking telephone number, the app is terminating

Comment: yes thats what i said you to post **crash log**.

Comment: Waiting for application to come online: com.example.helloworld.test | com.example.helloworld
Connecting to com.example.helloworld
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8611', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8611', transport: 'socket'

Comment: this is what the logcat shows...

Comment: tel: link is working properly on web pages, but in an app its not working

Comment: Are you running this on the emulator?

Comment: yes, as well as on android device...

Answer (score 0):

please check or post the crash log and check if it is a formatting/parsing issue. Intent.ACTION_DIAL doesn't need permissions so see if it works when using hard coded tel number like,

```
final Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:090909111");
startActivity(intent);
```